# How to overlap images in the header section?

Tags: html, css, header

How do you overlap two images in the header section? I want one of the images to be the background and the other to be on top of that image but `floating left`.
How would you position it? or is it better to use CSS and how?
 Please keep in mind that i am newbie in web designing. Thank you!

```
<div style="position:relative; left:0; top:0;">
    <h1>
     <img src="C:\Users\zacfre9292\Desktop\Favorite Music\JSC2.jpg" alt="Jesus Culture logo" width="1900" height="197">
    </h1> 

   <h1>
    <img src="C:\Users\zacfre9292\Desktop\Favorite Music\jesusculture logo.png" alt="Jesus Culture logo" width="700" height="200" >
   </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: use css z-index property and the div with greater z-index will be on the top while overlapping.

Comment: What tools/languages are you using?

Comment: I am just using notepad++. Noting advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a div with a image as background, then let the other image (and the header's content, if you have it) inside the div. Example:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#headerbg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/3S4zuof.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="headerbg" alt="image" style="text-align:center;">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Goy7oBy.gif" alt=logo style="max-height:150px">
</div>
```